# How to manage Android's filesystem from a Mac?

Tags: file-system, remote-access

Is there some way that I can explore, and possibly modify, my Android's file system from my Mac?  IOW, I would like to use my desktop Mac as the interface to access and modify my phone's filesystem, thus benefitting from full-sized keyboard and screen, mouse, etc.

(FWIW, my phone is rooted.)

Thanks!

Comment: As an extension question: I am wondering if the [Android File Transfer](http://www.android.com/filetransfer/) program works on rooted devices? I ask because if it does, then that's one possible answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

As your device is rooted, you could try to install come SSHd app:

- [QuickSSHd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.quicksshd) explicitly mentions root support
- [DropBear SSH Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.shkschneider.dropbearserver) even requires it
- [SSHDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid) mentions root as option

So all 3 of them should be able to "export" the full file system via SSH. So on a Mac (and Linux/Unix/BSD as well) you could directly connect from a terminal, or integrate the device's file system using e.g. [SSHFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sshfs) or [Fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files_transferred_over_shell_protocol), on Windows you could use the famous [WinSCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winscp) -- and probably many others.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to my question turned out to be rather trivial (at least for my rooted HTC Incredible). *Trivial to the point that I'm embarrassed I asked the question in the first place!*

To explore/manipulate my phone's file system, all I had to do was connect it to my computer via USB, and choose "Disk drive" as the connection type.

Then the storage on my phone shows up as two additional volumes: one for `/sdcard` and one for `/emmc`, which I can manipulate like any other volume.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, the approach as I've described it gives access only to those areas of the phone's file system that a user can modify without root access.

This approach is good enough for my purposes, but if you want free rein over your phone's file system, and don't mind going over to the "dark side" to get these powers, see this [XDA Forum Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1030107).